# Nested convex optimization

Tags: reference-request, convex-optimization

Suppose I have a convex optimization problem of the form $$\min_x f(x) ~~s.t.\\x\in X$$.  Say that $f(x)$ and its (sub)gradient are not given in a closed form, but are determined by solving a convex sub-problem of the form $$\min_y g(x,y)~~s.t.\\y\in Y(x)$$ where $Y(x)$ is a convex feasible region that depends on $x$.  Just to drive the point home, let's say that $g$ and its (sub)gradient are *also* not given in a closed form, but are determined by solving the convex sub-problem $$\min_z h(x,y,z) ~~s.t.\\z\in Z(x,y)$$, and this last sub-problem does have closed form expressions for the objective function and (sub) gradient. So, our whole problem effectively has three "levels".  What can I say about the complexity of my original problem?  How does the potential for numerical error propagate back up through the inner problems?

Answer (score 1):

This is known as [bilevel optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilevel_optimization).  My impression is that it is considerably harder than usual convex optimization, even numerically.